# how to delete header cache in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

In my htaccess file there is this :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7257608"
</FilesMatch>
```

Now, if I wanted to alter a css type file. the css will change if I refreshed the page. Other users still get the old css file because of the cache. what can I do on my side to let the users browsers recognize there is a change in the css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally rather than setting a cache age in the .htaccess, make sure you're configured to use `if-modified-since` which is documented in the [Apache Caching Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html), using the [mod_cache extension](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html):

Generally, it's as simple as this, with exceptions written for secured resources:

```
LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
<IfModule mod_mem_cache.c>
    CacheEnable mem /
    MCacheSize 4096
    MCacheMaxObjectCount 100
    MCacheMinObjectSize 1
    MCacheMaxObjectSize 2048
</IfModule>
```